# Do BrowserSync and Gulp complement or rival each other for drupal builds on localhost

Tags: drupal, gulp, twig, browser-sync

I have two questions:

1. If I have *Gulp* running on a *drupal* localhost build. Will adding *BrowserSync* into the mix make my refreshes any more efficient/automated?
2. I noticed that I still have to clear cache, and sometimes restart browser to see changes made to twig files (using *Gulp* only). Is this correct or can I make these changes auto refresh somehow?